# Compatibilidad entre versiones y arquitectura en Java

Tags: app, arquitectura, java

Cuando creo una aplicación con un kit de desarrollo de *Java* en concreto, por ejemplo, el de arquitectura de *64 bits* y la *versión 8*:

1. ¿Esta aplicación puede funcionar en cualquier máquina virtual (*JRE*)? ¿O debe de ser de la misma arquitectura y versión?
2. ¿Si quisiera correr mi aplicación en otra arquitectura tendría que usar el *JDK* equivalente para desarrollar mi aplicación?

Comment: Si, un JDK incluye la Máquina virtual java (JVM), por tanto, si tienes JavaSE 8, tendrás una JVM que corra aplicaciones de esa versión.

Comment: Te expongo mi caso: he desarrollado un app en windows 10 x64 con su correspondiente jdk y la quiero usar en mi raspberry (arm) con su jre. ¿Que tendria que hacer para que fuera compatible?

Comment: Que Sistema operativo tienes en tu raspberry?

Comment: Raspbian Jessie Lite:[pagina oficial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/), en [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian) viene mejor

Comment: Pues, no deberías tener problema en instalar JDK en tu raspberry, para saber que versión debes instalar, en la consola de Windows escribe: java -version, ello te da la versión y con esa información te vas a: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnes y te lo descargas en tu linux, lo instalas y listo. Raspbian Jessie Lite al ser una distribución de Linux, pues te descargas el de linux, el que soporte tu raspberry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para la respuesta hay que diferenciar entre dos variables.

- el *bytecode* producido por el compilador es independiente de la plataforma y se ejecuta en una variedad de implementaciones de maquinas virtuales, como [HotSpot](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136373.html), IBM J9, Dalvik, OpenJDK o otros más, independiente con que *SDK* fue generado.
- La versión de Java utilizado (Java6, Java7, Java8) espicificado como "target version" no puede ser más alto que la versión de la maquina virtual.

Así por ejemplo: código de Java compilado con una SDK de 64bits con "target version" Java 7 por ejemplo corre en todas maquinas virtuales de 32bits o 64bits de versión 7 para arriba.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte. Muy bien explicado